# Content script loads but css file is ignored with certain match patterns

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

In my Google Chrome extension I load content script using **manifest.json** like this:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sort=newest*"],
      "css":     ["content.css"],
      "js":      ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
```

When I now browse to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql?sort=newest&pageSize=15 the `content.js` is successfully injected, but the `content.css` is just ignored.

But when I change the matches pattern to just `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*`, both are loaded and applied correctly.

Is that a bug in Chrome or is using multiple asterisks in the URL not allowed? But why does it work for JS then? The [matches pattern documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) explicitly allows "<any chars>" in the path part of the URL. Any idea how to make that work, except from [injecting CSS styles into the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) manually?

I also tried without success:

- Adding `"permissions":["tab", "https://stackoverflow.com/"]` to the manifest
- Adding `"web_accessible_resources": ["content.css"]` to the manifest
- Separating content script declaration into two objects for JS and CSS

**Edit:**

It's getting worse. I just found include_globs and tried this instead:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches":       ["https://stackoverflow.com/*"],
      "include_globs": ["*/questions/tagged/*sort=newest*"]
      "css":           ["content.css"],
      "js":            ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
```

JS is injected only into the newest questions page, as it should, but CSS gets now applied to the whole stackoverflow site. Is CSS pattern matching just broken?

Comment: +1 for having "done your homework" before asking !

Comment: LOL - a little bit of homework was still missing...